# Looping Through Worksheets Excluding Specified Worksheets

Tags: excel, vba, loops, outlook

I want to grab data from specified worksheets within a single workbook and then create individual emails from those sheets.

The code doesn't execute the operation for each worksheet and then move to the next.

I also want to exclude specified worksheets from the operation.

I am leveraging Ron DeBruin's [RangetoHtml](https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/outlook/bmail2.htm) function in a separate module.

```vb
Sub ClientEvent_Email_Generation()
    
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim count_row, count_col As Integer
    Dim Event_Table_Data As Range
    Dim Event2_Table_Data As Range
    Dim strl As String, STR2 As String, STR3 As String
    Dim WS As Worksheet
    Dim I As Integer
    
    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
    
    For Each WS In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
    
    WS.Activate
    
    If ActiveSheet.Name <> "DATA INPUT" Then Or "FORMATTED DATA TABLE" Or "REP CODE MAPPING TABLE" Or "IDEAS TAB" Then
    
    count_row = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A10", Range("a10").End(xlDown)))
    count_col = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A10", Range("a10").End(xlToRight)))
    
    Set Event_Table_Data = ActiveSheet.Cells.Range(Cells(9, 1), Cells(count_row, count_col)) 
    Set Event2_Table_Data = Sheets("w61").Range(Cells(9, 1), Cells(count_row, count_col)) 
    
    str1 = "<BODY style=font-size:12pt;font-family:Times New Roman>" & _
    "Hello " & Range("L3").Value & ",<br><br>The following account(s) listed below appear to have an upcoming event<br>"
    
    STR2 = "<br>Included are suggestions for an activity which may fit your client's needs.<br>"
    
    STR3 = "<br>You may place an order, or contact us for alternate ideas if these don't fit your client."
    
    On Error Resume Next
        With OutMail
        .To = ActiveSheet.Range("l4").Value
        .cc = ""
        .bcc = ""
        .Subject = "Upcoming Event  In Your Clients' Account(s)"
        .display
        .HTMLBody = str1 & RangetoHTML(Event_Table_Data) & STR2 & RangetoHTML(Event2_Table_Data) & STR3 & .HTMLBody
        
        End With
        On Error GoTo 0
    
    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
    
    End If
    
    Next WS
    
End Sub
```

Comment: You need to qualify ALL your range and cell references: `WorksheetFunction.CountA(WS.Range(` and `WS.Cells.Range(WS.Cells(` for example. Why are you sometimes using `ActiveSheet` and sometimes using `WS` if they are the same thing?

Comment: You have an extra Then where it isn't needed so this code won't even compile: `If ActiveSheet.Name <> "DATA INPUT" Then Or "FORMATTED DATA TABLE"...` You only need the Then at the very end of that line

Answer (score 0):

### Loop (Iterate) Through Worksheets

- The following will loop through each worksheet in the workbook containing this code (`ThisWorkbook`) and print each worksheet name that is not included in the `Exceptions List` (`Exceptions` array) and the 'non-empty' range starting with cell `A9` to the `Immediate window` (VBE: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>.
- Run it first as-is to see if the result is satisfactory and only then add your email code (which is unclear) where you need to qualify the ranges and cells i.e. use `ws` instead of `ActiveSheet` and `ws.` in front of `Cells` or `Range` (`ws.Cells(...)`, `ws.Range(...)` if any of it is, or is part of the current worksheet in the loop.
- There may be more reliable ways (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-in-finding-last-used-cell-in-excel-with-vba/11169920#11169920) to *Error in finding last used cell in Excel with VBA*) to define (create a reference to) the range, but the focus here is set on the loop (using `ACount` is even less reliable).

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub loopThroughWorksheets()
    
    Const sFirst As String = "A9"
    Const ExceptionsList As String _
        = "DATA INPUT,FORMATTED DATA TABLE,REP CODE MAPPING TABLE,IDEAS TAB"
    
    Dim Exceptions() As String: Exceptions = Split(ExceptionsList, ",")
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet
    Dim srg As Range ' "Event_Table_Data"
    Dim fCell As Range
    Dim rCount As Long, cCount As Long
    
    For Each sws In wb.Worksheets
        If IsError(Application.Match(sws.Name, Exceptions, 0)) Then
            Set fCell = sws.Range(sFirst)
            rCount = sws.Range(fCell, fCell.End(xlDown)).Cells.Count
            cCount = sws.Range(fCell, fCell.End(xlToRight)).Cells.Count
            Set srg = fCell.Resize(rCount, cCount)
            ' e.g.:
            Debug.Print sws.Name, srg.Address
            
            ' Your email code (per worksheet) here.
        
        'Else
            ' Worksheet is in Exceptions Array: do nothing, or...
        End If
    Next sws

End Sub
```